# MQ | Sender LONGRTR

Tags: ibm-mq

I see `SENDER` channel goes into `RETRY` mode after `LONGRTS` start. It remains in `RETRY` mode and re-started after `LONGMTR(1200)` seconds. My question is - does Sender channel comes back to `RUNNING` as soon as message come, without completion of `LONGMTR` or it waits for `LONGMTR` time?

Answer (score 2):

A SENDER channel will go into `STATUS(RETRY)` - a.k.a. Retry Mode - when the connection to its partner fails.

To begin with, on the assumption that many network failures are very short lived, a SENDER channel will try a small number of fairly close together attempts to re-make the network connection. It will try 10 times at 60 seconds apart, to re-make the connection. This is known as the "short retries".

This 10 times and 60 seconds apart, are coded in the SENDER channel fields called `SHORTRTY` and `SHORTTMR`.

If after these first 10 attempts, the SENDER channel has still not managed to get reconnected to the network partner, it will now move to "long retries". It is now operating with the assumption that the network outage is a longer one, for example the partner queue manager machine is having maintenance applied, or there has been some other major outage, and not just a network blip.

The SENDER channel will now try what it hopes is an infinite number of slightly more spaced apart attempts to re-make the connection. It will try 999999999 times at 1200 seconds apart, to re-make the connection.

This 999999999 and 1200, are coded in the SENDER channel fields called `LONGRTY` and `LONGTMR`.

You can see how many attempts are left by using the DISPLAY CHSTATUS command and looking at the `SHORTRTS` and `LONGRTS` fields. These should how many of the 10 or 999999999 are left. If `SHORTRTS(0)` then you know the SENDER is into "long retry mode".

If, on any of these attempts to re-make the connection, it is successful, it will stop retrying and you will see the SENDER channel show `STATUS(RUNNING)`. Note that the success is due to the network connection having been successfully made, and is nothing to do with whether a message arrives or not.

It will not continue making retry attempts after it successfully connects to the partner (until the next time the connection is lost of course).

If your channel is in `STATUS(RETRY)` you should look in the `AMQERR01.LOG` to discover the reason for the failure. It may be something you can fix at the SENDER end or it may be something that needs to be fixed at the RECEIVER end, for example restarting the queue manager or the listener.

Comment: Great write up Morag, I would also suggest increasing the `SHORTRTY` and decreasing the `LONGTMR` as well to make sure the channel goes to RUNNING as soon as possible after the connectivity issue is resolved.  IBM never changes anything and those default values have been around for ages.  My suggested values are `SHORTRTY(120) LONGTMR(300)`, if the issue is resolved in under 2 hours it will go RUNNING within 1 minute, if longer than 2 hours it will go RUNNING with in 5 minutes.

Comment: Good advice to tune retries to your own environment. I didn't want to make the answer more complicated since the OP first needed to understand when retrying would stop. When tuning your own retry values, always make sure that LONGRTY is a long enough time period to cover everything because a channel will go into STOPPED status once all retries as exhausted.